# Convert a snippet of Delphi code to C++Builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder, eurekalog

I am working with the EurekaLog bug catcher for Delphi/C++Builder. All of their examples are in Delphi and I am using C++Builder. The Delphi code below is one of their examples that causes a software exception. I tried to convert this into C++ below but my code is wrong. Can you show me the correct C++ Code to make this work.

Delphi code from EurekaLog

```pascal
type
  EMyException = class(Exception);

Procedure TForm. ButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
 raise EMyException.Create('Error Message');
end;

end.
```

My C++Builder code that does not work

```cpp
typedef class{
  Exception;
}EMyException;

void __fastcall TForm1::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
  throw new EMyException("Error Message");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to derive a new class, not use a typedef.  And don't use `new` when calling `throw` (this is the *only* area in C++Builder where a `TObject` descendant must not be constructed with `new`).

```cpp
class EMyException : public Exception
{
public:
    __fastcall EMyException(const String Msg) : Exception(Msg) {}
};

void __fastcall TForm::ButtonClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    throw EMyException("Error Message");
}
```